# In $\triangle ABC$, if $\angle B=60^\circ$ and $\sin A\sin C=\lambda$, then what is the range of $\lambda$?

Tags: trigonometry

> In $\triangle ABC$ if $\angle B=60^\circ$ and $\sin A\sin C=\lambda$, then what is the range of $\lambda$?

Try: Using $$\cos B=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ab}$$

So $a^2-ac+c^2=b^2$. From $\sin A\sin C=\lambda$, substitute $$ac=4R^2\lambda$$
where $R$ is circumradius of $\triangle ABC$.

Could some help me how to calculate $\lambda$? Thanks.

Comment: That's one free variable, so find the range of $\,\lambda = \sin(A) \sin(120^\circ - A)\,$ over $\,A \in (0^\circ, 120^\circ)\,$.

Comment: Thanks dxiv .but i did not understand why we use $B=120^\circ-A$.

Comment: $\,\color{red}{C} = 180^\circ - A - B = 120^\circ - A\,$.

Comment: Thanks dxiv got it.

Answer (score -1):

$$\sin A\sin C=\frac12\bigg(\cos(A-C)-\cos(A+C))=\frac12\bigg(\cos D+\frac12\bigg)$$ where $D=|A-C|$ which lie between $0^\circ$ to $120^\circ$
So $-\frac{\sqrt3}2 \leq \cos D \leq 1$

So the range is from $\bigg[\frac{1-\sqrt3}4, \frac34\bigg]$

Comment: This would be a lot easier to read if you used some MathJax/LaTeX to format it.

Comment: So, the answer suggest that $\lambda$ can be negative,
despite that $\sin$ of any angle in a valid triangle is positive?